# Troubles with signs using d'Alembert's principle

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, conventions, constrained-dynamics

I am trying to find the equation of motion for the system below using d'Alembert's and virtual work principles, however I must be making a mistake since my equation doesn't match the solution that I have found online.

[image: System]

Assumptions: No friction, $m_1 = m_2 = m$, $l$ is the length of the rigid bar which connects Block 1 with Block 2, $\vec{g}$ goes down.

In order to apply d'Alembert's and virtual work principles, I can define the virtual displacements differentiating the following equations:
\begin{align*}
x &= l \cos \theta \\
y &= l \sin\theta
\end{align*}

Thus, the virtual displacements are:

\begin{align*}
\delta x &= - l \sin \theta \delta \theta \\
\delta y &= l \cos \theta \delta \theta
\end{align*}

Assuming that Block 1 goes down and Block 2 goes right, the equation for the virtual work can be written as:
$$
\delta W = m\vec{g} \cdot \delta\vec{y} - m\vec{\ddot{y}} \cdot \delta\vec{y} - m\vec{\ddot{x}} \cdot \delta\vec{x} = mg \delta y - m\ddot{y}\delta y - m\ddot{x}\delta x= 0
$$

The last equation becomes:
$$
m g l \cos \theta \delta \theta -m(- l \sin\theta \dot{\theta}^2 + l \cos\theta \ddot{\theta}) l \cos \theta \delta \theta - m(-l\cos\theta\dot{\theta}^2-l\sin\theta\ddot{\theta})(-l\sin\theta\delta\theta) = 0
$$
Simplifying, the equation of motion that I get is:
$$
-g \cos \theta + l \ddot{\theta} = 0
$$
while the solution that I should get is:
$$
g \cos\theta + l\ddot{\theta} = 0
$$
I can't understand why my signs in the equation for the virtual work (I guess) are wrong, I must have made a stupid mistake but I'm having an hard time trying to figure it out.

Comment: May be I wrong, but what about the sign of $\delta y$?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov Given the assumptions I made in the figure, it should be positive when pointing downwards, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the y-axis grows upwards, as would be natural from the picture, all the equations are the same, except for the sign of the force, that is now $-mg$.

If y grows downwards, and $y=0$ where the axis crosses, then $y = -lsin(\theta)$. If $y=0$ is the initial position of the mass, then $y = h - lsin(\theta)$ where $h = lsin(\theta_0)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however would you mind to explain why the force should be $-mg$? Assuming that the positive $y$-axis points downwards, $\vec{g}$ should be positive, thus the force would be equal to $mg$.

Comment: Now, I think my edit is correct.

Comment: I was just answering myself that, in my case, it must be $y = l(1 - \sin \theta)$, thank you for your help anyway!