# Deriving the equation of motion of a compound pendulum using d'Alembert's principle

Tags: classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

After having derived the equation of motion of a simple pendulum using d'Alembert's principle, I'm trying to do the same with a compound pendulum, however I have stumbled upon a problem.

Consider the compound pendulum in the figure below and assume: $m$ is the mass of the pendulum and its distribution is uniform, $l$ is the length of the pendulum, $G$ is the center of mass and $I_G$ is its moment of inertia.

[image: Compound pendulum]

In order to apply d'Alembert's  principle, I can define the virtual displacements differentiating the following equations:
\begin{align*}
x_G &= \frac{l}{2}\sin\theta \\
y_G &= \frac{l}{2}\cos\theta
\end{align*}

Thus, the virtual displacements are:
\begin{align*}
\delta x_G &= \frac{l}{2}\cos\theta \delta\theta \\
\delta y_G &= -\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta \delta\theta
\end{align*}
The equation for the virtual work can be written as:
$$
\delta W = m\vec{g}\cdot\delta\vec{r}_G - m\vec{\ddot{r}}_G \cdot \delta\vec{r}_G - I_G \vec{\ddot{\theta}}\cdot\delta\vec{\theta} = 0
$$
The last equation becomes:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & mg
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{l}{2}\cos\theta \\ -\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\delta\theta-m
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta\dot{\theta}^2+\frac{l}{2}\cos\theta\ddot{\theta} & -\frac{l}{2}\cos\theta\dot{\theta}^2-\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta\ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{l}{2}\cos\theta \\ -\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta
\end{bmatrix}\delta\theta -I_G\ddot{\theta} \delta\theta = 0
$$
Simplifying, the equation of motion that I get is:

$$\left(I_G + \frac{ml^2}{4}\right)\ddot{\theta} + mg\frac{l}{2} \sin\theta = 0$$

I can't understand why in this case, applying d'Alembert's principle, I must consider the term $- I_G \vec{\ddot{\theta}}\cdot\delta\vec{\theta}$, while in the simple pendulum it doesn't appear in the equation of the virtual work

Comment: \begin{align*}
\delta x_G &= \frac{l}{2}\cos\theta\delta\theta \\
\delta y_G &= -\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta \delta\theta
\end{align*}

Comment: @Eli thank you, would you mind to explain why you didn't include $\dot{\theta}$ in your equations? According to the chain rule and given i.e. $\delta x_G = \frac{\partial{x_G}}{\partial{\theta}} \delta\theta$, $\dot{\theta}$ should appear in the equations.

Comment: Look at this equation $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta }\dfrac{d\theta }{dt}\Rightarrow \delta x=\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta }\delta \theta $

Comment: @Eli thank you, now the equation that I get matches the solution (it looks like I made the same mistake yesterday in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/694169/troubles-with-signs-using-dalemberts-principle/ however I was lucky enough to get the correct result anyway). If you can help me with my other doubt and post an answer, I will accept it.